# How can I add dashes (custom formatting) inside a string of numbers?

Tags: php, jquery

I have a site where users enter a numeric code of 10 numbers:

```
xxxxxxxxxx
```

When displaying this value (read from the database), I want it to display in this format:

```
xxxx-xxxx-xx
```

How can I do this with PHP or jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$code = "1234567890";
echo substr($code, 0, 4) . "-" . substr($code, 4, 4) . "-" . substr($code, 8, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regular Expression.

```
$Text        = "1234567890";
$Pattern     = '/(.{4})(.{4})(.{2})/';
$Replacement = '$1-$2-$3';
$NewText     = preg_replace($Pattern, $Replacement, $Text);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

in jquery, for example:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        n = $("#IdOfTheElement").text();
        n = n.substr(0, 4) + "-" + n.substr(4, 4) + "-" + n.substr(8);
        $("#IdOfTheElement").text(n)
    }
</script>
```